# How to handle a transfer data from a postback to preinit event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, postback, onpreinit

Imagine a scenario in which I got two forms, first one, static, and second one, dynamic.
These forms are for a Student Pre-Regisration process.

The Form1 check whether a student with the ID (National Identity) exists or not. If 'exists' it will show the process of registration (something like, pending, accepted, such stuff). If 'does not exists', it means the second form should be visible to get filled by student. The second form is completely dynamic. All fields, etc are dynamically created in PreInit.

In addition to StudentID, I have to pass a FormID too. FormID is very important because there are other forms too and also the dynamic form will be generated based on it.

My problem is how to transfer the StudentID (txtStudentID.Text) to the dynamic form.
I have tried many scenarios but they does not work properly, like ajax panel, page1 & page2, etc.

I'd highly appreciate if you give me a practical solution.

Form 1:

```
//Request.QueryString["FormID"];
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Form 2:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        CreateDynamicForm(StudentID);
    }
}
protected void CreateDynamicForm(Guid StudentID)
{
    //  codes for generating the dynamic form, based on the StudentID submited form Form1, and FormID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Init-fase is to initialize your page. The PreInit-fase is before the Init-fase and during PreInit many things are not initialized, like your MasterPage and your Context. My advise: use PreInit rarely.

In either case you shoule be able to make use of the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.

This Request-part contains all data which are send from the client to the server. In there is a collection called "Form" with all the data from the webform, entered by the user.

This data is meant to be used to fill all your controls at your page, but filling these controls happens AFTER your page is initialized, zo AFTER OnInit.

At this point in the life cycle of your page you can only access the form values by this Form-collection like:

`string studentID = HttpContxt.Current.Request.Form["txtStudentID"];`

There is one pittfall. Some page-elements, like a MasterPage, could modifiy the ID's within it. They are there own ID before the ID of the inner control. So the ID "txtStudentID" could have become: "ctl00$contents$txtStudentID". (which means there is an outer control with the ID "ctl00", in there a control withe the name "contents" and in there the control "txtStudentID".

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I did as you mentioned but it gets null: protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string x = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["txtSID"];
            base.OnInit(e);
            AddButtons();
        }
    }

Comment: It tested my own answer. In OnInit as well as OnPreInit, HttpContext.Current is already avaiable (in my testcases). I tested with V2008 / .NET3.5 and VS2012 / .NET4.5. Try to test in your code if HttpContext.Current is NULL, if HttpContext.Current.Request is NULL, if  HttpContext.Current.Request.Forms is NULL. If one of them is null, you get a NullReferenceException. In that case we should find out why your context is not initialized correctly.

Comment: I'm confused about using HttpContext.Current.Request.Form. In fact it's for the first time I'm using it. Using a loop I got the value but don't know how to get directly: for (int i = 0; i < HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Count; i++)
                div.InnerHtml += string.Format("{0} : {1}<br />", HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetKey(i), HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues(i).GetValue(0).ToString()); Part of RESULT: ctl00$contents$txtSID : 2343333434

Comment: I wonder why but I got the value of txtSID using : HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ctl00$contents$txtSID"].ToString() in a case the ClientIDMode is set to static

Comment: Danke Schoen Martin :) You did a big favor to me and simplified my form. Thanks a lot :)